# Double key trap ctrl with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a code in which :

- When user double presses the ctrl button,
- an object's css property changes

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).keydown(function(){
    setTimeout(function(e){
        var count_keypress = 0;
        if (e.keyCode == 17) {
            count_keypress +1;
        }
        if (count_keypress == 2) {
            $("#iframe_add_update").css(
        "display" , "inline"
          );
        }
    },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var tapStarted = false;
$(document).keydown(function() {
    if (e.keyCode == 17) {
        if (!tapStarted) {
            tapStarted = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
               tapStarted = false; 
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            /* DO STUFF! */
            tapStarted = false;
        }
    }
});
```

The idea here is that the first time ctrl is pressed, the press is remembered but a timer is started which will FORGET the first press after 1000ms (you can change the value to anything obviously - 1000ms may be too long).

The user must hit ctrl for the 2nd time before the timer negates the 1st press.

Comment: What should be the best time period for the timer.

Comment: I'm a little confused, how the 2nd press is detected ?

Comment: Both presses are detected via the same keydown function; the first press sets the "tapStarted" variable to true, but also sets a timer to reset tapStarted to false after a certain delay. If by the time the second press occurs the timer has not fired, the value will still be true, and code will proceed to the 2nd branch of the if statement. Try 300-400ms? it depends on taste I suppose :)

Comment: had any luck with this? :)